# discord.js 13 | How do i DM a member a message when they join the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to find a way to DM a member a welcome message when they join the server. I have a way to DM the member, but I can't find a way to trigger it when someone joins. here's the code that will DM the member a message:
`message.author.send('message content here')`

Here's the code that doesn't seem to work:

```js
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    log("new member joined the server")
    member.send("Welcome to the server!");
});
```

*Note: I have a function called log, this is not what's causing the issue (i think), it's declared before this*

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't working, most likely, because you haven't requested the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent which is necessary for the [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) event.

Here is a simple example on how to request the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent.

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS],
});
```

Make sure you have also enabled it in your bot's settings. (Bot -> Privileged Gateway Intents -> SERVER MEMBERS INTENT)
[image]